# How can I connect to the Oracle Developer DB VM on MacOS?

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, rodbc, r-dbi

I am running the [Oracle Developer DB VM](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html) on Virtualbox. On my local I am running macOS and have downloaded Oracle's [SQLDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html). I have successfully connected to the database using the configuration found [here](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-mac/#c5). I am hoping to connect the the database in R, for example [like this](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/oracle/):

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  Driver = "[your driver's name]",
                  Host   = "localhost",
                  SVC    = "[your schema's name]",
                  UID    = "hr",
                  PWD    = "oracle",
                  Port   = 1521)
```

I have also tried connecting to the database using [ODBC Manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) and [iODBC Administrator](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads) but am having trouble finding any driver & driver manager configuration that will have a successful connection like I got from SQL Developer. Every error I've gotten implies the configuration is wrong. I'm hoping to translate the successful SQL Developer connection into either a successful R connection or a connected DSN.

Comment: SQL Developer comes bundled with an Oracle JDBC driver. You probably want to [install the Oracle ODBC driver with the Oracle Instant Client and set up unixODBC](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/installing-the-oracle-odbc-driver-on-macos)

Comment: Also "SVC" is probably the same as "Service Name" from your SQL Developer config.